# Strange build errors in MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am writing a port scanning application in MFC C++ using Visual Studio 2010. When I try to compile, I get >100 errors, all connected with the files `atlcore.h` and `afxcomctl32.h`.

All of them are error #C3861, "Identifier Not Found."

I have not edited these files in any way. Anybody know why this would be doing that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you `#include <windows.h>` first? `#include "stdafx.h"`?

Comment: Try to minimize your program (to the point where it does nothing at all) and make sure that it compiles. Then add parts of it back again step by step until you see which parts it is that cause the problems you are seeing. Most likely you have forgotten to add an #include statement or similar, but by narrowing down the parts that cause the problems this way it is much easier to find out what the missing thing is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out! the reason it was not compiling and throwing all those error is because I'm using VS 2010 on a Windows XP, and the MFC support is for OSs Windows Vista and up. I tried compiling my code in Visual Studio 2008 and it worked, so I guess I just will have to use VS 2008 for MFC C++.

Comment: More likely the defaults for the target platform changed in stdafx.h - I'd check there.